# Sessions doesn't working

Tags: php, html, session

Hi i have a problem with the use of session.
I create the session here

```
 <?php session_start();

include('MConsultas.php');
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];

$Objeto = new Consulta();
$consulta="SELECT * from persona where Email='".$mail."'";
$Rset = $Objeto->querys($consulta);

if ($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($Rset)) {
    $contraseña1=hash('sha512',$contraseña);

            if ($fila['Contrasena']==$contraseña1)
            {

                $_SESSION['IDuser']= $fila['ID_Persona'];
                $_SESSION['IDnombre']= $fila['Nombre'];
                $_SESSION['IDemail']= $fila['Email'];
                $_SESSION['IDempre']= 'NULL';
                $_SESSION['IDAbogado']= 'NULL';
                $_SESSION['Autentica'] = "si";
                $_SESSION['Tipo']="persona";

                echo $fila['ID_Persona'];

                echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = '../administrador/personas/mis-casos.php'; </script>";
```

}

And i try to use the session here:

```
<?php session_start();



    if($_SESSION['Autentica'] == 'si')
    { 
    if($_SESSION["Tipo"] == "persona" || $_SESSION["Tipo"] == "empresa")
    {


    ?>
```

But this php, doesn't recognize the session.
Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Looks like you have whitespace before the `<?php` which can cause issues with sessions because output has started and the cookie can't be sent after that.

Comment: why do you think php doesn't recognize the session here?

Comment: It's not that, i tried to put session_start() everywhere and still doesn't work